# python, webscraping, and writing a file

Tags: python, request, urllib

I am using 3 modules in this program, I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible! So I want to scrape some data off of twitter and write it in a text file using python, can somebody please guide me and tell me why my code isn't writing the data scrapped?

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from os import path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# here I define the url, I request the page, create my soup
theurl = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

def create_file(dest):
    """
    Creates a file for the user to write data in!
    :param dest:
    :return:
    """
    ## FileName == Month_Day_Year
    name = 'Data Scraped.txt'

    if not(path.isfile(dest +name)):
        f = open(dest + name, "w")
        f.write(soup.title.text)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    destination = 'C:\\Users\\edwin\\' \
              'Desktop\\WebScrappin\\'
    create_file(destination)
    print("Your file has been created!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only the writing the title of the document that you received.

```
        f.write(soup.title.text)
```

Instead of scraping (which is [against their ToS](https://twitter.com/tos?lang=en)) you should gather your data from their [RESTful API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) or use a library like [Twython](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: im not scrapping twitter completely, im just trying to figure out how to put the title in a text document, all written in my python code. i dont understand ur response, i have that in my code. is it in the incorrect spot?

Comment: I'm referencing that you're only writing the title. Scraping any part of their site is against ToS.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you run this code?

Comment: Oh i didn't know should i just erase the code from my comp?